# What eactly does Bundler complain about?

Tags: ruby

The error message is as follows:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
    active_model_serializers (~> 0.10) was resolved to 0.10.12, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 4.1, < 6.2)

    lograge (~> 0.10) was resolved to 0.11.2, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 4)

    rails (~> 5.2.0) was resolved to 5.2.4.4, which depends on
      actionpack (= 5.2.4.4)

    rspec-rails (~> 3.8) was resolved to 3.9.1, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
```

I completely do not understand what is the problem here. If I aggregate the above list, the requirements for `actionpack` are:

- (>= 4.1, < 6.2)
- (>= 4)
- (= 5.2.4.4)
- (>= 3.0)

And `actionpack 5.2.4.4` satisfies all of the above -- but why the hell does Bundler complain???

Comment: What command were you running when this occurred?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your Gemfile, please?